# Connect a mail.live.com address to an office365.com account - unusual activity

Tags: outlook.com, office-365

My mail.office365.com aka outlook.office.com account has asked me to reconnected my mail.live.com account. This is what I have tried.

## 9:24 am at mail.office365.com...

1. Clicked Settings > Mail > Connected accounts > New
2. Added my mail.live.com email (foobar@outlook.com) and password.
3. Clicked OK.

[image]

The result says

> Unsecured connection: A secured connection couldn't be established to this account. Not all providers offer secured connects. **Click OK to try an unsecured connection.** Click Skip to configure your account settings.

## 9:25 am at mail.live.com...

foobar@outlook.com inbox receives an email from the Microsoft account team, which cues me to "Review recent activity." I can see that activity but have no other action for me to take.

[image]

## 9:32 am at mail.office365.com...

1. Clicked **OK to try an unsecured connection.**
2. Microsoft tells me, "We couldn't connect to the server for you other account..." and cues to me to choose either POP or IMAP.
3. I try with both IMAP and POP.

IMAP failed with this message:

> A test connection to that account wasn't successful. Either the email address or password that you typed isn't correct.

POP failed with this message:

> Couldn't log on to the specified mail server because either the username or password was rejected.

I have verified that POP is enabled at my outlook.com account and have double checked my POP and IMAP settings.

[image]

I am at a loss of what to do, because I know that both the email and password are correct.

My best guess is that this has something to do with the "Unusual activity" in my foobar@outlook.com account, and that I somehow have to allow this sign in attempt. That is, the unusual sign-in activity email said:

> To regain access, you'll need to confirm that the recent activity was yours.

How do I confirm that the recent activity was mine?

Comment: I closed this question because it's +6 years old, it had been bumped 39 times and have not attracted activity. Apparently it is not interesting / helpful for this community.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with my accounts. Now solved...

You have 2 accounts: 1st = main and 2nd = to be connected. 
Go to 2nd account settings (web) > activate POP

Go to 1st account > start connection of 2nd account 
Step 1: user name and password > it will fail and will be able to click Skip to provide some additional settings 
Step 2: provide all required settings, incl. pop server and SSL flag > click to Connect > it will check your settings and fail with this message "... rejected" > do NOT click "Back"

It's the problem:
Go to 2nd account > check your mails > in inbox or junk you will have a mail like "... bad activity" with URL to activities page > click on it

(you will need probably to provide a confirmation code and so on)

Solution:
2nd account > On activities page you have to click "It's me" > like confirm that the (last) activity is OK!
1st account > now, click "Back" and without any changes click on "Connect" again > it will be able finally to verify your account and connect your 2nd account to 1st!

PS: I personally spend 2 evenings solving it and called support that was absolutely not able to help me.